# Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore

I have an error this is my Logcat

```
2020-07-26 12:14:50.756 30507-30507/com.tuto.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tuto.myapplication, PID: 30507
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tuto.myapplication/com.tuto.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.tuto.myapplication:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout: Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)       android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1016)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onCreateView(BaseArFragment.java:162)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:851)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1079)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1007)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
2020-07-26 12:14:50.758 30507-30507/com.tuto.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.tuto.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/filament/gltfio/Gltfio;
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.EngineInstance.gltfioInit(EngineInstance.java:96)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.EngineInstance.createEngine(EngineInstance.java:110)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.EngineInstance.getEngine(EngineInstance.java:42)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderer.initialize(Renderer.java:542)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderer.<init>(Renderer.java:109)
    at com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.initialize(SourceFile:37)

   2020-07-26 12:14:50.759 30507-30507/com.tuto.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.filament.gltfio.Gltfio" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 53 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
2020-07-26 12:14:50.759 30507-30507/com.tuto.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:130)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:75)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:914)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1015)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1264)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2611)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7075)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:296)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2208)
            ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.tuto.myapplication-R6xbR4NAzgk5zRoAjKzIxA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:130)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:75)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:914)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1015)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1264)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2611)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7075)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:296)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2208)
            ... 6 more
```

this is my code
MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Scene.OnUpdateListener {

private customArFragment mCustomArFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mCustomArFragment = (customArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        mCustomArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void setUpDatabase(Config config, Session session){
    Bitmap nature = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.nature);
    AugmentedImageDatabase aid = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
    aid.addImage("nature" , nature);
    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    Frame frame = mCustomArFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    Collection<AugmentedImage> images = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
    for (AugmentedImage image : images){
        if (image.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING){
            if (image.getName().equals("nature")){
                Anchor anchor = image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose());
                createModel(anchor);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void createModel(Anchor anchor) {
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this , Uri.parse("untitled.sfb"))
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> { placeModel(modelRenderable,anchor); });

}

private void placeModel(ModelRenderable modelRenderable, Anchor anchor) {
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    anchorNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    mCustomArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.tuto.myapplication.customArFragment"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

customArFragment :

```
public class customArFragment extends ArFragment {
@Override
protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session) {
    Config config = new Config(session);
    config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
    config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
    session.configure(config);
    this.getArSceneView().setupSession(session);

    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setUpDatabase(config,session);

    return config;
}
```

}

//EDIT1: Just edited the stacktrace in order to be exploitable.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same error with AVD for API 29. In SDK Manager, for your selected API level, download **"Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image"** or **"Intel x86 Atom System Image"** or all "Google API intel...."

Note: Above downloads requires huge space and data

Then faced another error "Google Play services for ar keeps stopping"

for this error below link helped
https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/emulator

So here is the answer

Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher.
Make sure your emulator is configured to use the latest version of OpenGL ES:
Click More in the running emulator's toolbar.
Select Settings > Advanced > OpenGL ES API level > Renderer maximum (up to OpenGL ES 3.1).
Restart the emulator. When prompted, do not save the current state.

Check more on link above

Comment: Thanks for this. I redownloaded Android Studio and was scratching my head for hours on why my app no longer worked.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this type of error seems to be running on devices which don't support OpenGL ES3.1 or later - see the discussion here: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/4

This can be either on older or less capable devices or when running in the emulator on a platform that does not have this version or a later version.

There are also reports that having mismatched Sceneform libraries can cause the same problem (not sure if the error is 100% the same) - i.e. an example from the discussion above (with version bolded to highlight):

> implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:**1.10.0**"
>
> implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform:animation:**1.8.0**"

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle Add the following configuration to the file.

```
android{
....
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
```